# $this->redirect in cakephp 3.0

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect

im already pulling my hair with this bug.
I'm writing a normal cakephp website with 3.0.
Problem is redirects wont work (they only redirect to blank pages).
Even this line in my Controller will only redirect me to a blank page

```
public function test(){
    return $this->redirect('/');
}
```

If i call "url/pages/test", I will only get a blank page displayed. I checked most of my files for blank spaces and didnt find any.
The results are all the same on IE, Firefox and Chrome.

I know the main problem is another header being sent before the location header.
Is there something i might be missing, because this is only a controller call with the redirect (no extra layouts etc.).

Looking forward to your help!

Comment: Did you right anything in your pages/test.ctp file ?

Comment: check for spaces before php opening tag in your controllers and models loaded

Comment: @AlimonKarim I dont even have the test.ctp created, cause i dont use a layout...

Comment: @ArmanPetrosyan I checked all my Controllers and models again, but cant find any space before the php opening tag. I'm using PHPStorm 10, if this is a related bug there. Going to try on a local server now, maybe the error is caused by my server

Comment: is your error reporting enabled to show all errors ? from what line it is getting first output ?